# How to periodically fire getLoaderManager().restartLoader()

Tags: java, android, scheduled-tasks, loader, scheduledexecutorservice

I try to "continuously" load data from web service. I have build AsyncTaskLoader to load data from web service, it is working fine.

Now I try to fire loader every 5 second (wait 5 second after previous loader run is finished). For that I try to use ScheduledExecutorService, scheduleWithFixedDelay() looks right for this use case.

Now I have something like this:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    scheduleTaskExecutor= Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            fireLoaderHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
        }
    }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

private Handler fireLoaderHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        restartLoadet();
    }
};

private void restartLoadet() {
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this).forceLoad();
}   

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<Vehicle>> loader, List<Vehicle> data) {

    for(Vehicle vehicle : data) {

        Marker marker = mMarkerHashMap.get(vehicle);

        if(marker == null) {
            Marker m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(vehicle.getLocation()).title(vehicle.getName()));
            mMarkerHashMap.put(vehicle, m);
        }

        else
        {
            marker.setPosition(vehicle.getLocation());
        }
    }
}
```

This "works" but is the ScheduledExecutorService really waiting before the loader finishes and start counting the 5 sec delay? I think this is now more like fire and forget stuff?

Overall what is the correct way to implement this, periodically fire loader's restartLoader()?

**UPDATE**

Added onLoadFinished() to code example. So Im using loader to get list of objects from web api. These objects are used to draw markers to map. I also store marker and my vehicle object mapping in mMarkerHashMap, so I can update marker location when I get the same object (with updated location) in upcoming loader (web api) responses.

Comment: You shouldn't be scheduling actions for Loaders - it's designed as a passive loading mechanism: you start it, and you periodically get updates **as and when content is updated**. "... [Loaders] should monitor the source of their data and deliver new results when the contents change.  See {@link android.app.LoaderManager} for more detail."

Comment: So I need to build the web service polling to loader itself? Or use completely some other approach?

Comment: It's difficult to answer without understanding what you're trying to do. Ideally, yes, the web service would push to the app saying an update is available (GCM). In most cases, you'll poll; use AlarmManager (or JobScheduler if you can) to poll the web service checking for updates at sensible intervals. Cache this data (typically in a database) where you'll use your Loader to update the UI as/when content in your cache is updated.

Comment: Im basically fetching vehicle locations from web api (sending get requests). The api returns json response and with the help of gson, i build list of objects. Based on these objects I draw Markers to map. The api is "realtime api" so the response changes every second or so. Ideally I would call the web api every second, but to save bandwidth and battery, something like every 5 sec should be ok.

Comment: For me, it's not clear how a Loader would be used in this situation, and my instinct is that it's not going to be helpful. You can edit your question with this information, and state how you are using loaders to achieve this goal (what do you do `onLoadFinished()`?) but it feels like the answer you need is different from the question you've asked (aka, close and new one)

Comment: Updated the original question. You are right, maybe loaders are not right for this. Im quite new on android and loaders where the first to come in my mind. Feel free to suggest something else to approach this :)